# want to create a variable, increment it and get new value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i'm creating a bunch of textfields. i am stacking them vertical, so i use:

```
CGRectMake(193, ((i * 45) + 45), 240, 30)
```

then after each textbox is created, i increment i.

```
int i = 0

CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(193, ((i * 45) + 45), 240, 30)
UITextField *myTextField01 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
//format and add to view text field
i++;

//create next text field
myRect = CGRectMake(193, ((i * 45) + 45), 240, 30) //can i get rid of this line?

UITextField *myTextField01 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
//format and add to view text field
i++;
```

i need to reassign the myRect to get i updated to the value of 1.

is there a better way to do this so i don't need to reassign myRect to get the update value of i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGRect` is a struct, so you can increment the internal fields directly:

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(193, 45, 240, 30);
UITextField *myTextField01 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];

myRect.origin.y += 45;
UITextField *myTextField02 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];

myRect.origin.y += 45;
UITextField *myTextField03 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
```

I would also use a loop and some kind of container (probably `NSArray`), but that's a side topic `;)`

Comment: this works well, i ditch having to reassign myRect each time and would just replace the i++ with this.

Comment: Glad to help, but I assure you that the "cost" of reassigning that `CGRect` structure is so close to zero that you should have no reason to worry about it. Beware of [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)!

Comment: hehe, wasn't that i was going for optimization, i just got tired of copyig/pasting that line so much  =D

Answer (score 2):

Use `myRect = CGRectOffset(myRect, 0, 45);` each time. "i" is not used here because you offset the already offset rectangle.

Comment: this works to get rid of the int i, but i would still need to reassign "myRect" after each text box. i was hoping not to have to do that.